# properties of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:Show that if w1,w2 are given vectors and r different from 0, then the equation rv +w1 = w2 has exactly one solution v

any suggestions or hint ? I would really appreciate

Comment: Inverse elements of vector addition and scalar multiplication are unique, so you can just solve for $v$ like you're used to.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack exchange. What are your thoughts on the problem so far? Telling us will make it easier for us to help you and is considered polite as it makes us feel as we are helping you learn instead of doing homework.

Comment: hello, so while thinking of it I thought of changing its form into v=(w2-w1).1/r but then I did not get it how to proof that v is unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $w_1,w_2$ are fixed, and you started from the assumption that $v$ is a solution, it follows that $v$ is the particular vector
$$v=\frac1r(w_2-w_1)\,.$$
So it's actually *uniqueness* it deduces.

Multiplying back to the original equation readily verifies that it is indeed a solution.